# Upload the image with JSON parameter in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am just trying to upload the image with json parameter in NSURLSession swift 3

url:"http:xxxxxxxx"
the JSON parameter : {"data":{"userId":9}}

Please help me to accomplish it

Here is the code:

```
func UploadRequest()
{
    let username = "v"
    let password = "v"
    let loginData = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64LoginData = loginData.base64EncodedString()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginData)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    if (imageView.image == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1)


    if(image_data == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: image_data! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){

        data, response, error in

        self.loading.stopAnimating()

        if data == nil{
            print("data is nil")
        }
        else
        {
            print("data is\(data!)")
        }

        if error == nil{
            print("error is nil")
        }
        else
        {
            print("error is \(error!)")
        }

        if response == nil{
            print("response is nil")
        }
        else
        {
            print("response is \(response!)")
        }

        print("hitted")

        guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(dataString!)

    }
    self.loading.stopAnimating()

    task.resume()

}

func jsonToNSData(json: AnyObject) -> NSData?{
    return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []) as NSData
}

func generateBoundaryString() -> String
{
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}
//[String:[String: Int]]?

func createBodyWithParameters(filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    let param:[String:Any] = ["data":["data":["userId":9]]]


    do {


       for i in param {

          body.appendString(string:"--\(boundary)\r\n")
         body.appendString(string:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(i.key)\"\r\n\r\n")
          body.appendString(string:"\(i.value)\r\n")

        }

        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: [])

        let filename = "user-profile.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString(string:"--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(decoded)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendString(string:"\(decoded)\r\n")

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    return body
}


extension NSMutableData {

    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

In the backend aim getting error as ["userId":9] cannot deserialize it

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like it could be related to the way you are both serialising, deserialising then converting the dictionary to a string then back to data again. You can see this in the use of the decoded property instead of the jsonData when creating the request payload.

Instead of `body.appendString(string:"\(decoded)\r\n")`

Why not try:

`body.append(jsonData)
body.appendString(string:"\r\n")`